# Backbone.js EL and Template in the View

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js

So i'm very new to backbone.js and not so good at JavaScript in general, so I was wondering if someone could explain to me why

I cannot define my EL property, and Template property in my view, and then use this.template in my render.  Instead I have to define the template and el in my render function.

```
    var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#product-list'),

    initialize: function() { 
            this.el.html('<span style="color:white">loading...</span>'); 
    }, // end initialize


    render: function(collection) { 
    //    // assign the template 
          this.template = $('#product_template');

          // Where the template will be placed  
          this.el = $('#product-list'); 

          // Add the collection to the main object 
          this.collection = collection;

          // add tthe data to the html variable 
          var html = this.template.tmpl(this.collection.toJSON());

          // place the html in the element. 
           this.el.html(html);

           // not even sure what the hell this is. 
          return this;      
        }   // end render  

});
```

Comment: You don't have to do this. `this.el` should be set by the time `initialize` is called (but you should use `$(this.el)` - `el` is generally the DOM element, not a jQuery object). You can define the template in `initialize` if you prefer. Are you getting errors?

Comment: Also, `return this;` is a Backbone convention that allows chaining, e.g. `$(parent).append(view.render().el)` - you can't use that last `.el` in the same statement unless you return the view in `.render()`.

Comment: The code I have is working for me, but it doesnt look like anything i've seen in the tutorials, so i'm thinking i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Right, but does it throw some kind of error if you do it the way I describe?

Comment: I'm not getting an error when I do it your way, its just not rendering the collection.  And if I do a console.log($(this.el)); inside the render function  I get undefined

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't in the way you're defining `el` or `template`, it's in how you're setting the call back. In `Workspace`, your router, you're setting the callback for your collection refresh event like this:

```
// Bind the view and collection 
// So when the collection is reset, the view executes the render method
Products.bind("reset", this.view.render);
```

The problem is, you're setting a method as a callback, but you're not providing a context object as the third argument to bind - so the method is called, but `this` in the method refers to the global object, *not* the view. So `this.el` is undefined, because it's not looking at the view instance at all. Try:

```
// Bind the view and collection 
// So when the collection is reset, the view executes the render method
Products.bind("reset", this.view.render, this.view);
```

and see how that goes.

(I made a jsFiddle to demonstrate that the `el` and `template` were set properly under normal circumstances, though it doesn't actually include the fix above, which is hard to mock up without the server-side data: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/QjgS9/)

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this:

```
var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#product-list'),
    // ...
```

and get anything useful in `el` as `#product-list` probably isn't even present in the DOM when your ProductView is built; so trying to use `$('#product-list')` for `el` is simply the classic "I forgot to use `$(document).ready()`" problem dressed up in Backbone. Using `$('#product-list')` for `el` should work if `#product-list` is around when you *define* your ProductView though.

You can do this though:

```
var ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#product-list',
    // ...
```

and then say `$(this.el)` when you need to do things inside your view methods. Not only is `$(this.el)` the usual way of using `el` but it also works and that's sort of important.

The same issues apply to `#product_template`.

---

Looking at your code I see this:

```
// INstantiate the view 
this.view = new ProductView(); 

// Bind the view and collection 
// So when the collection is reset, the view executes the render method
Products.bind("reset", this.view.render);
```

Presumably the `render` is being triggered by the reset event. But, and this is a big but, the `render` method isn't bound to the right `this` anywhere so `this` won't be the `ProductView` when `render` is called and `this` won't have anything that you expected it to; hence your bizarre "undefined" error.

You could use [`_.bindAll`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll) in your `initialize`:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    // ...
```

but usually you'd want to give the view a collection when you create it and the view would bind itself to the events so your structure will still be a bit odd.

You can also supply a context (AKA `this`) when you call [`bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-bind):

```
collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
```

Comment: el: '#product-list',
     template: '#product_template', 

Console.log returns // undefined.

Comment: +1 - this looks like the probable answer. @Gamak, are you logging these attributes after the DOM is ready, or before?

Comment: After the DOM is ready, at least I think.  I have it all wrapped in $(function() {
});

Comment: @Gamak: `$(this.el)` is undefined?

Comment: Yes $(this.el)  is undefined in the render function.

Comment: @Gamak: The jQuery function should never return `undefined`, an empty array sometimes but never `undefined`. Any chance of seeing a quick demo on http://jsfiddle.net/? Something strange is going on.

Comment: here is the live link [To my Example](http://dev.firesquire.com/sevendrumworks/kit_builder2.html#products/starphonic).  Just view source, all the JS is on the page.

Comment: @Gamak: Your problem isn't in `render` so much as how `render` is being bound/called. Have a look at my update.

Comment: As of Backbone 0.9: If you have been writing a fair amount of `$(view.el)`, there's now a cached reference for that jQuery object: `$el`. http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-$el

Comment: @Myster: That's also part of the reason that we have [`View#setElement`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-setElement) now.